# Django Flatpages url loads the same template

Tags: python, django

I have extended the FlatPages app based on http://linfiniti.com/2011/01/bending-django-flatpages-to-your-will/

I am trying to implement catchall url pattern for the flatpages .

Here's the pattern on url.py under the main main app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^.*/$', include('app.modules.cms.urls')),
)
```

and this pattern is on the extended flatpages module

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.modules.cms.views',
    (r'^(?P<url>.*)$', 'flatpage'),
)
```

When I try to view the different pages that I created through the admin. They all show the same template. On inspection using django toolbar, I noticed that url isn't being passed to the flatpages view function,

```
View Function                   args    kwargs
app.modules.cms.views.flatpage  None    url=
```

Am I using a wrong regex pattern or do I need to anything more to make it work.

/Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) seem to recommend doing it this way...

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^(?P<url>.*)$', 'app.modules.cms.views.flatpage'),
)
```

...although it might work this way...

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^/', include('app.modules.cms.urls')),
)
```